# How to call Script of post method which is in innerHtml in angular8+?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, api, angular8

I am getting the response from API which consist of html and inside that I have script of post method.
I binded the html through **[innerHtml]** then I want to hit the script which is of post method from Angular8+.

How do I hit the post method which is in the **[innerHtml]**?

**Explanation in brief**
I got complete html from API response, it holds form with two input field for ex:-
`form name="example" method="post" url="www.google.com"`
`input type="text" value="name"/`
`input type="text" value="passsword"/`
`/form`
in it and post method for ex:- `script document.example.submit /script"`.

When I get the response I will open the html which I get from response in model window by binding it to [innerHml]. for example :-
`div "#exp" [innerHtml]="response"  </div`,
which will display the html content but with the content I have the form which should be auto posted and it should open external form.

can be opened in different tab or on top of the present website.

Comment: Could you add more details/post what you've tried so far?

Comment: @JoshMathews I have updated the question below "Explanation in brief", please look into it.
Thank you.

Comment: @user79161 I have removed the tag "Java".

Comment: @JoshMathews, I got the solution, but it is in Jquery, It will be good If I get the relavent answer in typescript instead Jquery.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

I got solution by using Jquery, which worked for me.

I coded Jquery inside ngAfterViewInit().

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void 
{ 
$(document).ready(function () {
$('form[name="Bankfrm"]').submit();
});
}
```

I used "name" instead "id" because I dont have id in-side form.